# How to acess the actual bone rotation?

Tags: python, drivers

I want to write a operator that adds a driver to a shapekey.
so the shape key can be controlled by a bone.

the main idea is that the current position of the bone becomes the value 1 for the shape key, this can be done by dividing the driver variable value by the current position of the bone.

but is there a problem:

if I add an option for using bone rotations too, I need to get the rotation of the bone but it has three rotation modes and none of these matches the driver variable if I set to X,Y or Z rotation modes and when the bone rotation mode is changed the driver variable changes too.

so I need to get the real rotation of the bone in the current type of rotation or the current driver variable value for build the expression.

how can I do this?